# Having chapters shown as numbers and roman letters

Tags: chapters, roman-numerals

I am fairly new to LaTex and currently using it for writing a thesis.
In my paper I have a page for Preface, Acknowledgements and a list of used Abbreviations before my list of content. The list of content is followed by the Introduction to my thesis. The "issue" here, is that I want every chapter before my table of content to be listed as "Chapter I", "Chapter II" etc (Roman letters) while every chapter AFTER my Table of content to be shown as "Chapter 1", "Chapter 2" etc.

is there any way to do this?

MWE of how it *currently* works:

```
\documentclass{report}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text

\begin{document}  
\pagenumbering{arabic}  
\chapter{Abbreviations}  
\lipsum[1-2]  
\section{Some extra special abbreviations}  
\lipsum[1-2]  
\subsection{Some math}  
\lipsum[1-2]  
\tableofcontents  
\chapter{Introduction}  
\lipsum[1-2]  
\end{document}
```

The listed MWE is how it currently is, but what I want changed is the "Chapter 1" on the "Abbreviation" chapter. I would have that, and the sections/subsections in Roman letters, and have the "normal" numbering (Chapter 1, Section 1, subsection 1.1 etc) start at the "Introduction" chapter.

I know I can remove the chapter 1 part from the Abbreviations with

```
\chapter*
```

but I'm still missing how to add the "Chapter II" instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Define `\thechapter` to do `\Roman{chapter}` in the frontmatter, then reset the `chapter` counter and redefine `\thechapter` to the standard `\arabic{chapter}`. I also add code for `hyperref` compatibility.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\usepackage{hyperref} % if you want it

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text

% uncomment the following line if using hyperref
%\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\arabic{chapter}\thechapter}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\chapter{Preface}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Acknowledgments}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Abbreviations}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Some extra special abbreviations}
\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{Some math}
\lipsum[1-2]

\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to get Roman numbers also for the subordinate counters, do

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}
```

at the start and

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
```

before Chapter 1.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly! Just need to get the sections and subsections to do the same, but I guess it would work to just define the section command and then redefine it would work the same way?

Comment: @Neq I'll add the definitions.

Comment: This works when I put in into my example, but when I add it into my own thesis where I got a few more packages and have the different chapters added by the \input{folder/nameoffile} to the main file, it gives me another dot between sections and subsections. 
So instead of saying Chapter.Section.Subsection as: I.II.IV it shows it as Chapter.Section..Subsection or: I.II..IV  
Will try to figure out whats causing it.

Comment: Found the problem. I had a chapter missing a \section, so it basicly only had "Chapter..Subsection" so it wasn't and extra dot, it was just the section missing. Fixing the chapter by adding the \section that was supposed to be in there solved the issue.